# "Unexpected unknown type selector in sonarlint"

Tags: css, angular, lint, sonarlint

I am using SonarLint in my Angular project. For pagination, I used NG Bootstrap pagination. But Sonarlint shows me issues like `unexpected unknown type selector "ngb-pagination"`. How do I exclude these types of tags from getting detected? And also in which file, do I change such kind of rules?